# Having trouble coming up with a way to have an AI system spawn at certain points on a connect 4 board

Tags: c++, console

I successfully made a connect 4 board that allowed two players to face one another and got it all working. But now I am trying to an AI to it but I'm having an issue that I'm unable to resolve.

Essentially I am wanting the AI to get all of the game squares in my 9x9 grid that are empty but have square underneath them which is not empty - as are the rules of connect 4.

Because my grid is a two dimensional vector, I imagine that the choice of movement for the AI would be 8 possible positions - because that's the width of the board. I am trying to save 8 possible positions - for example board[4][6], [board[5][6] - and then have the AI randomly select a position to spawn on.

Sorry if that's a really unclear explanation, I find it really to portray my intentions with programming.

I have some code that somewhat achieves this by spawning a game piece on top of an existing game piece but of course I am hoping to somehow store these coordinates and then have the AI randomly choose one position.

Thank you so much for your time.

```
// AiOnBoard.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


namespace game
{
    const char EMPTY = ' ';
}

void spawn(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& board)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
        {
            if(board[row][col] == game::EMPTY)
            {
                int tempRow = row;
                if(tempRow < 8) //So it doesn't exceed the bounds of the vector.
                    tempRow++;
                if (board[tempRow][col] != game::EMPTY)
                {
                    //std::cout << "Row: " << row << ". Col: " << col << "\n";
                    board[row][col] = 'O';
                    //return;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

void displayBoard(const std::vector<std::vector<char>> board)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
    {
        std::cout << "\t";
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) 
        {
            std::cout << "|" << board[row][col] << "|";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

}

void initBoard(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& board)
{

    std::vector<char> tempBoard;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        tempBoard.push_back(game::EMPTY);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        board.push_back(tempBoard);
    }

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> board;
    initBoard(board);

    board[5][4] = 'X';
    board[5][2] = 'X';
    board[4][6] = 'X';

    spawn(board); 

    displayBoard(board);



    char c;
    std::cin >> c;



}
```

Comment: So what is the problem, [generating random numbers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for a position? Checking if the generated position is empty or not? Something else?

Comment: Looking for a way to store up to 8 possible movement positions on the board and then randomly choose one of them. The code above spawns a game piece on each position that is allowed.

Comment: There are up to 9 possible moves, so why only allow it to pick from 8 of them? And since the moves are really all the same - put the piece on the lowest available space on the column - it might be simpler to have it just randomly pick a column (an int from 0 to 8) and then calculate where it can go and put the piece there, rather than storing the possible moves. Unless you intend to later have it analyze the board and choose the best column

Comment: That is a good suggestion and I'll try it implement that thank you. But as storing each position you could then determine what is the best move to make because the AI could block a player from winning on next turn or win on next turn.

I know how to code that I think it's just the storing of the positions and possibly accessing them is where I am having the issue.

Comment: I was hoping you would. Randomly moving opponents aren't as fun haha. Why not create a vector with 9 elements in it, each representing a column, and store the row that it can move to in each element?

Comment: Not quite sure how I would do that. Sorry I am rather new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've used C++, so please forgive any errors in the code.

Basically, what you seem to be looking for is a vector containing all of the possible moves that can be made. You pretty much have that in your code already. You find the spots that can be moved into, now you just need to store that in a vector.

```
void findMoves(std::vector<std::vector<char>>& board)
{
    std::vector<int> moves;
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (int row = 8; row >= 0; row--)
        {
            // find the first empty spot from the bottom up
            if (board[row][col] == game::EMPTY)
            {
                moves.push_back(row);
                found = true;
                break; // don't check the rest of the column
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            moves.push_back(-1); // the column is full to the top
        }
    }

    // now you have all the available moves
    // you can analyze these moves in this function or
    // change the function from void to vector<int> and
    // return moves so it can be passed to another function
}
```

Note that I've swapped the loops so that it checks column by column instead of row by row, and checks the rows from the bottom up to save time.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. I made a slight alteration so I have two vectors holding the row and column positions. Then I access them with a random number.

Comment: Sounds good. Good luck with the rest of the AI. Connect 4 is a fun game to write AI for, at least in my experience